# Issue in sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to change `nw_src` in the following string:

```
cookie=0xb868a1f26498cddd, duration=5327.613s, table=0, n_packets=199, n_bytes=19502, priority=30,icmp,in_port="qvo2495b490-33",nw_src=10.0.0.133,nw_dst=8.8.8.0/24 actions=group:2
```

command used:

```
sed -i -e
's/nw_src=(^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$,)/nw_src=1.1.1.1/g' flows.txt
```

It seems to not work however when i generate data from regex: it shows all the permutation of generated data right.

```
I am just trying to replace nw_src=<any_ipv4_address> to nw_src=1.1.1.1
```

Also nw_src appears only once in line

What am i missing.
Please help

Comment: You are trying to change it to what? To 1.1.1.1? Why does the regexp have to be so complicated - do you have to verify that the input, like 10.0.0.133, is a valid four-part IP address? What if it isn't? Also, why do you need `/g` at the end - can `nw_src` appear more than once on a line?

Comment: Also, in your regular expression you are using `^` and `$`. Those are markers for the beginning and the end of the line of text; they make no sense where you used them.

Comment: i am just trying to replace nw_src=<any_ipv4_address> to nw_src=1.1.1.1       also nw_src appears once only

Comment: You need specify that you want extended regular expressions, so you need a `-E` or `-r` option.  Note that dotted-decimal notation does not allow leading zeros, so the `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` term is too generous.  The caret will cause grief, as already noted.  You are probably using GNU `sed`; it allows `-i` on its own.  BSD `sed` (used on macOS too) requires an argument for the `-i` option, so it would treat the backup suffix as `-e`.  If you want an empty backup suffix on macOS, you must use `-i ''` — so there isn't a portable way to backup in situ between these dialects of `sed`; use `-i.bak`.

Comment: I don't know if you understood my question. Do you need to verify that the input value of `nw_src` is a valid IP address? Can it be something **other than** a valid IP address, and you should only change it if it's a valid IP address, but leave it unchanged otherwise? If it is guaranteed that it's always a valid IP address, **or** if you need to change it in all cases regardless of validity, you don't need to verify that the current value is a valid IP address - and the code can be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the regular expression that verifies that a text fragment is a one, two or three digit substring, representing a numeric value between 0 and 255:

```
2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]
```

For example, run the following command and inspect its output:

```
seq 0 999 | grep -E '^(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])$'
```

`seq` generates all integers from 0 to 999, one per line, and grep will return only the integers from 0 to 255. Note that I had to enclose the regexp in parentheses, so that the anchors `^` and `$` apply to the whole thing. In general, you need to have the regexp preceded and followed by non-digits, or by some sort of zero-length assertions to make sure the string is not a substring of a longer sequence of digits.

If you must replace the value of `nw_src`, but only when it is a valid IP4 address (and leave it as is if it's not a valid IP4 address), you could do this:

```
sed -iE 's/\bnw_src=(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.\1){3}\b/nw_src=1.1.1.1/'
```

If it is guaranteed that the "old" value is always a valid IP4 address (so you don't need to verify that in this command), **or** if you need to replace the "old" value regardless of whether it is a valid address or not, the command can be simplified quite a bit; for example

```
... 's/\bnw_src=[^,]*/nw_src=1.1.1.1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is `replace nw_src=<any_ipv4_address> to nw_src=1.1.1.1` then the following will suffice

```
sed 's/\(.*nw_src=\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\11.1.1.1,\2/' network_file
```

Output

```
$ sed 's/\(.*nw_src=\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\11.1.1.1,\2/' network_file 
cookie=0xb868a1f26498cddd, duration=5327.613s, table=0, n_packets=199, n_bytes=19502, priority=30,icmp,in_port="qvo2495b490-33",nw_src=1.1.1.1,10.0.0.133
```